# LinkedIn API Error: "serviceErrorCode": 100, "message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET-handleString /clientAwareMemberHandles", "status": 403

Tags: permissions, postman, linkedin-api

I got the access token using the following permissions:

> **r_emailaddress**, **r_liteprofile** and **w_member_social**

But when I try to do a GET request using the below link,

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/clientAwareMemberHandles?q=handleString&handleString={someone@email.com}
```

I get the following Error:

```
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 100,
    "message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET-handleString /clientAwareMemberHandles",
    "status": 403
}
```

and with **`/people`** also I get the same error,

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people/(id:{_us123456)}?projection=(id,firstName,lastName)

Error:
        {
            "serviceErrorCode": 100,
            "message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET /people/(id:%7B_us123456)%7D",
            "status": 403
        }
```

Can someone let me know what permission am I missing? How do I resolve this issue?

FYI, I am able to do a GET request to `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me` with the same access token and it returns the appropriate JSON on Postman.

Answer (score 1):

You must make sure you mention all the scopes you had asked for permission unless it wouldn't work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling for the same problem i think the doc says : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/handle-lookup

> The use of this API is restricted to those developers approved by
> LinkedIn and subject to applicable data restrictions in their
> agreements.

I think all you need to do is be a partner of linkedin :(